# Last output not appearing

Tags: java

I'm just getting back on the programming horse so I'm doing some basic problems in Java on CodeAbbey.com. I am given a standard input where the first integer in the input is the number of pairs followed by all subsequent inputs being pairs of numbers. I input this by just running the code and pasting it then using Scanner to read it. My code is supposed to add together each of those pairs of numbers individually then output each answer separated with a space.  For example:

```
data:
3
100 8
15 245
1945 54

answer:
108 260 1999
```

Here is my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            int sum = in.nextInt() + in.nextInt();
            System.out.print(sum);
            if (i < size) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code actually works, but the issue is that it is not initially outputting the last sum. It prints all the sums up to the last one, but I have to press enter again for the last sum to print, and it prints one line down from all the others. This happens no matter the number of pairs or the platform I'm using; the last sum never prints until I once again hit enter. Any idea as to why this is occurring?

Comment: There are invisible <enter> characters at the end of every line except the last one.  You're not adding "One extra enter", you're making up for the missing enter in your dataset.  In the future, please be more specific about exactly what you are doing to input that data, a lot of us had to scratch our heads to imagine what you could possibly be doing wrong, since the program is working as you say it should.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` won't receive any input until Enter is pressed.

When you press Enter, the line of text, e.g. "1945 54", is entered into the scanner.  Now it can return the next `int`.  The `Scanner` will block until it can read sufficient input, and if you don't press Enter yet, it will remain blocked.  That is why pressing Enter allows the program to print the sum.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, because of the way the input is formatted each line besides the last essentially has an <enter> code already. Therefore for the last line I need to manually press enter or Scanner won't get the input. Is there a way to write it so I don't have to manually press enter without changing the way the input is formatted?

Comment: Whether you type the Enter yourself, or the input is redirected from a file, the newline character after the last line must be present.

Answer (score 0):

Until you hit enter, it is hanging on the input routine, because you might actually be preparing to add a more scannable data (or another digit to the last number) you typed.

Answer (score 0):

You should split the printing out part in a seperate loop not in that for loop that also asks for value inputs.

So with the code you have currently modified would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            int sum = in.nextInt() + in.nextInt();
            System.out.print(sum);
            }

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
            if (i < size) 
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

splitting it should stop you needing to press enter before it prints the last value